# Prove dependence among order statistics

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n$ be independent and identically, random variables with $X_1 \sim {\cal Exp}(1)$.

Define $Y_1 = X_{(1)}, Y_k = X_{(k)}-X_{(k-1)}, 2\leq k \leq n$, show that $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots Y_n, Y_{n+1}$ are dependent ,where $Y_{n+1} = X_{(1)} + X_{(2)} + X_{(3)} + \ldots + X_{(n)}$.

Could anyone help me with this very straightforward and easy question? Thanks so much.

Comment: $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots Y_n$ are independent.

Comment: $P(Y_1>y,Y_{n+1}<y)=0 <P(Y_1>y)P(Y_{n+1}<y)$.

Comment: @A.S. I think it makes sense. But it is hard to think about it this way. What I have tried first is try to find joint distribution...... How do you think about this?

Comment: @A.S. Do you mind write your comment as an answer?

Comment: Look for some relationships between variables that constraint possible values. Instead of looking for joint distribution, compare distributions of $X$ and $X|Y$. For example you know that it must be the case that $Y_1<Y_{n+1}$ but both can take any positive values, so the variables cannot be independent. In other words, $Y_1$ and $Y_1|Y_{n+1}$ have different support so they can't have the same distribution.

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much.